# how to delete a database in mysql to export a database with same name?

Tags: php, mysql, wamp, wampserver

Until yesterday everything was fine. 
Everything I did i create a .sql file of a database and reinstall wamp server and i gave a password for localhost. After restarting the PC I was able to access the database without having importing it.

But today there is no table inside the database.

So i tried to export it but failed since the name already exists. So I rename it and tried to export and getting the error message:

Error
SQL query:

```
-- --------------------------------------------------------
--
-- Table structure for table `cgpa_details`
--
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS  `cgpa_details` (
   `cgpa_id` INT( 11 ) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
   `usn` VARCHAR( 7 ) NOT NULL ,
   `sem1` FLOAT NOT NULL ,
   `sem2` FLOAT NOT NULL ,
   `sem3` FLOAT NOT NULL ,
   `sem4` FLOAT NOT NULL ,
   `sem5` FLOAT NOT NULL ,
   `sem6` FLOAT NOT NULL ,
   `sem7` FLOAT NOT NULL ,
   `sem8` FLOAT NOT NULL ,
 PRIMARY KEY (  `cgpa_id` ) ,
 UNIQUE KEY  `usn` (  `usn` )
 ) ENGINE = INNODB DEFAULT CHARSET = latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT =4;
```

MySQL said: Documentation

1813 - Tablespace for table '`ssitdashboard`.`cgpa_details`' exists. Please DISCARD the tablespace before IMPORT.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

restart mysql.
    ALTER TABLE cgpa_details DISCARD TABLESPACE;

EDIT:
    DROP TABLESPACE  'ssitdashboard.cgpa_details'

Also check this link: http://mysqlhints.blogspot.ro/2008/10/fixing-innodb-import-tablespace-error.html

Comment: but there is no table in the database. I can not drop the table

Comment: Even after restart you cant drop it?